# Mongodb text search (exact match, fuzzy match)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

we're using mongo text index for entity search among multiple fields.
Something really confused me is the results returning by the text search of mongo.

**Context**

Supposing we have a User collection containing firstname and lastname string fields. A text index has been added with both fields.

```
await collection.createIndex({ firstName: 'text', lastName: 'text' }, { name: 'users_text_index' });
```

And the User collection has the following two documents:

- the first document : {_id: xxx, firstname: "firstname", lastname: "lastname" }
- the second document : {_id: xxx, firstname: "firstname1", lastname: "lastname1" }

We implemented using NodeJs a search with the following text search syntaxe (where the "keyword" is a incoming argument represents the keyword used by the final user)

```
{ $text: { $search: keyword } }
```

**Result**

- when we search with "lastna", we got both documents
- when we search with "lastname", we only got the first one (which is an exact match)

**Question**

I'm wondering why, once we got an exact match, the second document will no longer be returned by mongo ?

What can we do, other than replacing the text search by a collection of $Or conditions with regex on each searching field, in order to always return all matches (exact match and similar matches) ?

Thanks a lot